# Attach JSON key, value pairs to a javascript object

Tags: javascript, json, object

If I have some JSON:

```
{
  "foo":"1",
  "bar":"2"
}
```

Is it possible to dynamically attach it to a javascript object?  For example, I could have a function:

```
myObject.eatJSON(data)
```

which would then allow me to do something like:

```
myObject.foo // "1"
myObject.bar // "2"
```

**Edit**

The JSON is now JSON.  I stupidly put "data =" in front of it. Trust me it's external JSON.

Comment: try data.foo or data.bar

Comment: You are already declaring a JS object.

Comment: Your code creates JavaScript object `data` with two properties. You do not need to parse anything.

Answer (score 1):

Most libraries have some function built-in for that. For example, in underscore.js I would use [extend](http://underscorejs.org/#extend):

```
_.extend(myObject, data);
```

By the way, `data` isn't JSON; it's a Javascript object. It would only be JSON if the whole thing were a string, such as:

```
data = "{\"foo\":\"1\", \"bar\":\"2\"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var dataObj = JSON.parse(data)
for (var key in dataObj)
  myObject[key] = dataObj[key]
```

Comment: That's what I mean, but how can an object perform this action to itself?

Comment: Well you could write a slightly similar method (that uses `this` instead of myObject) and attach to a prototype, eg, `Hungry.prototype.eatJSON = function(data)`, then all objects that inherit from Hungry's prototype can eat JSON. But ask yourself this: is that better than a standalone function that simply takes two arguments (obj and data) and does the same thing? This is JavaScript, embrace functions!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach properties from a JSON file to an object by doing this:

```
class Foo
  constructor: ->
    data = JSON.parse './path/to.json'

    for key, value of data
      this[key] = value
```

(With coffee script).  Now if my JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "foo":"1"
  "bar":"2"
}
```

a 'Foo' object will do this:

```
obj = new Foo
obj.foo // "1"
obj.bar // "2"
```